# Assign id for each element after splitting from a sentence

Tags: javascript, php, html

I will like to ask how to assign a fixed id for each array after split. Let me do the explanation, $output is the sentence which have been retrieve from the database, "I# love to # read books.". Which actually means the delimiter which I have use in the code below is "#", so to allow the sentence to split. So now I will like ask how can I assign a fix id for each split element. Which means "I" will be id1, "love to" will be id2 and "read books" will be id3. How can I do that? I do not want it to be hard coded because the whole sentence was retrieve from the database. I want it to split and assign for each element.

```
<script>
var js_var = "<?php echo $output ?>";
var div_id = ['id1','id2','id3','id4','id5','id6','id7','id8','id9','id10'];
var box_id = ['box1','box2','box3','box4','box5','box6','box7','box8','box9','box10'];
var original = js_var.split("#");
var balls90= js_var.split("#");
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
x.innerHTML = balls90.join(" ");

</script>
```

Comment: What's this got to do with PHP or HTML5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily with a simple `for` loop, here is the code:

```
var js_var = "<?php echo $output ?>";
var div_id = ['id1','id2','id3','id4','id5','id6','id7','id8','id9','id10'];
var box_id = ['box1','box2','box3','box4','box5','box6','box7','box8','box9','box10'];
var original = js_var.split("#");
var balls90= js_var.split("#");

var x = document.getElementById("demo");
// I assume you want to use the balls90 variable
// and you want to add the divs to the #demo element

for (var i=0; i < balls90.length; i++) {
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.id = div_id[i];
    el.innerHTML = balls90[i];
    x.appendChild(el);
}
```

Then your HTML code will become something like this:

```
<div id="demo">
    <div id="id1">I</div>
    <div id="id2">love to</div>
    <div id="id3">read books</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to ask if I want to put them all of them horizontal instead of verital how can i display them? I have tried using display:inline-block and display:block in the style but did not work. Hope you can help:)

Comment: Add a css rule: #demo div { display: inline-block;}

Comment: I have face problem in my work. I had edit the code above. Hope you can help me.